# Xcode error: unable to find sdk 'macosx.internal' (in target 'libdispatch')

Tags: xcode, libdispatch

I'm compiling Apple *libdispatch*.
But there was an error
Error: `unable to find SDK 'macosx.internal'` (in target '*libdispatch*')

Does anyone have prior experience with this error?

Comment: Please provide your code.
The error message seems to provide valuable advice.

Comment: @DaniDev Code: 1. Go to https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/libdispatch and download/clone the pro.  2. Open `libdispatch/libdispatch.xcodeproj`.  3. Hit the run button or hit File menu > Run.

Answer (score 7):

Build Settings -> Base SDK -> macOS

[image]